# Google Map Renders Static Image Instead of Fully Functional Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I ran into a very strange issue that can only be reproduced in one of our environments. I tried debugging it and I found that as long as the canvas is 800px or smaller in width, it will render. However, the map becomes non-interactive and I can no longer get the bounds through map.getBounds(). Specified center point is also not plotted on the map.

This is working fine on all our development laptops. It just doesn't work when we deploy it to testing environment. Has anyone ever experienced this issue?

This is the data that I send though the call.

```
var options = {
    "zoom": 16,
    "center": new google.maps.LatLng(37.808582967132, -122.41495248394),
    "mapTypeId": "roadmap",
    "disableDefaultUI": true,
    "scrollwheel": false,
    "draggable": false,
    "disableDoubleClickZoom": true
};

new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map_canvas'), options);
```

API key is specified and the same one is used on development laptop so I don't think that's the case, but who knows.

---

### Update:

It seems that even when I reduced the size of the container element, it's only returning a static image of the map and that's why it's not interactive and also why it's only rendered when width is at most 800px. I have tried using the same API key in our production environment and a few laptop and they all work fine. It just doesn't work on a test environment that we have. I have double checked to make sure that the API is not being initialized twice and that we are using v3 API. The next test is to replicate the whole environment and also change domain name to see if it's somehow being restricted by Google. I have seen that some people had an issue due to internet connection, but I doubt that's the case since it doesn't work consistently no matter how fast the internet is.

Comment: You should add more information about the environments you have this working/not working in.

Comment: Since this is complete in Javascript, I didn't think it matters. Or does it? It's consistently not working across all browsers also. The only difference is that this is hosted on EC2. In the same environment, it's working for a case where it pretty much takes up the full screen. For this case, it's wrapped in a div that has size and the map canvas itself has width/height = 100%.

Comment: The markup/CSS matters because it determines what the canvas element inherits for dimensions.

Comment: @Jake I understand that marker up/CSS matters. However, I don't understand why it doesn't work only when it's deployed on that particular environment.

Answer (score 1):

After spending quite a bit of time running experiments, I finally found a workaround for the issue I was facing. I'm still not quite sure why I have to do this, but it seems to do the trick.

The key different that I forgot to mention is that all Javascript files are minified in the environment that's the map isn't working properly. This means that the script is loaded much faster and potentially executed before Maps API is loaded since it's loaded dynamically internally. Because of that I thought if I register a callback, the problem will be solved, but that's not the case.

Ultimately I had set timeout to switch the context. This is working very reliably so far.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    /*map loading logic*/
}, 1);
```